# Edit Item Workflow Starting after Item Creation

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created the following workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 :

[image]

Which sets the current item's review date to next year.

It also automatically approves the item for submission (this is due to the fact that this workflow should only run after an item is edited, so new items should still need approval)

These are the workflow start options :

[image]

However, whenever I create an item, the workflow is executed and the item gets auto-approved.

**Note that I had to create a 2010 workflow for this, as 2013 workflows don't have the action which sets the item's approval status**

Can anyone help explain why the workflow is being started after creation?

Comment: Have you gone through http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118204/workflow-automtically-starts-when-an-item-is-created-despite-it-being-unchecked ?

Comment: @AakashMorya Thanks for the link - I tried those solutions but with no effect

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to make sure that you published the WF and you can verify that you have the latest version (check WF version history).

The other workaround is to create a column (single line of text and call it NewWF and default value is Yes), then check the option to start the wf on start.

the first step of your workflow will be check the value of that NewWF column
`if the value = Yes` (meaning the item has just been added) set it to `No`!
`If the value = No` (meaning the item has been edited) run your logic...

HTH!

Comment: Hi Ahmend, thanks for your answer. I have checked the version history and everything seems in order - I will try your workaround but probably as a last-ditch effort as it is not that clean. I'm pretty sure SharePoint is the most irritating thing in the universe though.

Comment: Hello again Ahmed, I forgot to mention that I was running the workflow the "approving" user, which seems to be the reason why the items were being approved. After creating an item as a normal user, the item is not being approved (due to permissions), but the workflow is still (annoyingly) running at creation. This seems to be an alternate workaround to the one that you posted (as long as the approving user doesn't need his items approved!) - however when the item is then edited by the normal user, this requires approval so I am back to square one!

Comment: I am highly intrigued by that issue :) I will to recreate it on my environment and let you know if I find anything that helps solving the big mystery