# How to Disable Approval Workflow When Editing List Item

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, versioning, approval

I have a list which users are able to submit new contacts to, but these contacts need approval before they can be accessed by everyone.

In order to achieve this, I went to :

`List` -> `List Settings` -> `Versioning Settings` :

[image]

As you can see, I selected `No` for `Create a version each time you edit an item in this list?`, however whenever a list item is edited on this list (after being created and then approved), it goes back to being in a `Pending` state and requires further approval.

This then causes an infinite chain reaction where, if an item is approved after an edit, this approval counts as editing the item and so the document goes back into `Pending` state.

Is there a way of preventing this? Ie I would like to require approval on **Create** but not on **Edit**, and I also need another workflow which I created to run each time an item is edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `if condition` for the approval block with the workflow status hidden field.

- Create on hidden column called `IsApproved` & give default value as *No*
- At the time of new item creation inside the approval block, Update the `IsApproved` field as `Yes`
- In the workflow check if IsApproved equal to false then go to approval
  Please refer the below image

[image]

Or else you dont want to trigger the workflow for edit list item at all. You can uncheck the **Start workflow automatically when the item is Changed** in the `Start Options` of workflow settings.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, many thanks for your answer. This doesn't quite do what I need, because when editing an item, the actual Approval status will still be set to `Pending`, even if my custom edit workflow does not perform the actions I would need for an `Approve`d item. I need a workflow to run on each edit, but no requirement for approval at edit.

Comment: Your welcome. What your saying is after the task is approved the status is not changing?

Comment: It does change for a second, but then after I refresh it gets set back to `Pending`. I think this is because approving an item counts as an edit, because the `Approval Status` column is being amended. I only want new items to require approval.

Comment: In simple way you can have 2 workflows 1 for create new item and another one for Edit item.

Comment: This does not behave correctly when used in conjunction with the built in `Approval` option, as creating an item seems to set off the changed item workflow (see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179339/edit-item-workflow-starting-after-item-creation). I could just do all of the approving via custom workflows, but then what is the point of sharepoint?? PS SharePoint sucks

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a column, maybe call it newWF as a  (single line of text) and set to default value to Yes.

in your wf, check the value of that column, if it is equal yes(meaning it is a new item), run your logic, but dont forget to set the column to No after you finish.

if the value is no do nothing or skip.

not the most elegant solution, but it works!

[image]

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for your answer. I actually need another workflow to run when an item is edited - just not the appraval. I don't know how I can access the actual Approval workflow, as it is built in SharePoint 2013

Comment: You can create another workflow and attach it to the library that runs  when the item is changed! 

Also, since it is a SP 2013, you can start a wf within a workflow...I am updating the screen shots in my answer above!

Answer (score 1):

at least for my situation I found a workaround. It consists in applying an action at the very end of my status change workflow of ¨set content approval¨ and I just assign approved. This makes my list item to automatically go back to approved again when somebedy changes the status of the ticket.