# SP Designer workflow set to start on "modified" also starting on "created"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Sorry for the French parts, I will translate.

Here, you can see I did set my workflow to start when an item is modified, not created:
[image: Is set to start automatically... when modified]

Here, you can see I even put a condition : If modification by Supervisor
Send an email
[image: If modification by Supervisor]

My problem is : the workflow is starting both on modification AND on creation.
Question: what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. Of course I did google it: [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118204/workflow-automtically-starts-when-an-item-is-created-despite-it-being-unchecked) did not help me though...

Comment: Do you have any other workflows running on creation of that type of item?
 Running any workflow on an item, is in reality changing the version of the item and hence SharePoint would think that the item is in fact changing. Can you check the version of a newly created item?

Comment: Yes, I have another workflow running on creation (that allows the supervisor to make a change). Now I understand what was the issue, thanks to you. I guess I will have to erase the 'start on modified' workflow and modify my 'start on modification' workflow... How can I accept your comment as my answer?

Comment: I don't know how it works exactly since it's a comment not an answer. I will post an answer and you can accept that! Glad to help :)

Comment: @NathalieDesrosiers Welcome to the SharePoint StackExchange! You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is most often caused by a version increment. Check whether you have another workflow starting on creation of that type of item. If yes, that is most likely to be your problem!

1. First the user creates the item (Version 1)
2. The "other workflow"
   starts on creation (Version 2)
3. 2 fired a modification in the item,
   as shown in the version number, so the workflow supposed to run on
   modification of the item is fired.

You would have to re-configure your workflows' settings to not cause that kind of clash.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably updating a field in your workflow and since your workflow is set to start every time an item is modified. It is starting a workflow again and again. 
Review your workflow steps and make sure you do not update the current item, all updates should be done through the form, before you submit.